# How to verify the Access Token on the Shopify_App splash Screen

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

When the app review team uninstall and reinstall my app with their automated tools, they are getting an error because the uninstall webhook has not yet triggered the delayed job to delete the Shop record.  I think that's then tripping up the install process because it is finding the old shop record with an invalid access token.

I've been advised that:

> ```
> You should not be relying on an uninstalled webhook to determine a shop's status with your app. instead, each time a shop hits your app,
> ```
>
> you should make a request to your server to first determine if the
> access token you have for them is valid (if so, they have your app
> installed - if not, redirect to OAuth) and then from there check for a
> valid charge ID using the billing API (if not, redirect to billing
> page).

How should I check the api key validity?  When the app is installed they are redirected through splash page, so I need to somehow know if it's a new install and if it is,  check the access token  somehow?

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to tell what's wrong without knowing your architecture or request auth flow, so the solution could be somewhere else. Embedded apps redirect to shopify domain where Shopify checks if app URL is added to the store. If not it will return "There is no page at this address".

Answering your question -> the easiest way would be to make an API to /admin/shop.json request and see if you get a 401.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  The architecture is as per the shopify_app gem's demos and instructions.  amazing it doesnt cover this

Comment: @Will is that embedded app? I am building one too according to shopify practices and this question worries me a bit

Comment: Yes. bit more info here:  https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app/issues/1591  - I'd really make sure you have all this working before investing time on other features, but the app was approved and working, and I cant recreate the bug and am not getting much back from shopify.   think a bit of nerves is justified!  there are a lot of reports on shopify slack of similar issues,  some of which have been resolved, so i just need to work out how exactly

Comment: But the uninstalled app shouldn't be accessible from the admin panel. Iframe won't load with the "there is no page at this address" error. Webhook doesn't change here anything.

Comment: the problem is shopify are rapidly installing and reinstalling so quickly my webhook hasnt deleted the record in the rails app db.  so when they reinstall it gets the old record instead of creating a new one and now the access token is invalid

Comment: at least, thats my theory.  they seem to think error details are state secrets